# File name has two backslashes C#

Tags: c#, file, datetime, save, filenames

There is probably an easy answer for this, but when I added `DateTime.Now.ToString()` to my fileName it adds an extra \ for every \ I have so `C:\Temp` becomes `C:\\Temp` which causes the file not to save.

This is the code in question

```
String fileName = @"C:\Temp\data_" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".txt";
```

For example the output could be `C:\\Temp\\data_12/04/2012 20:08:40.txt`

It should be `C:\Temp\data_12/04/2012 20:08:40.txt`

Comment: It's not - this is just how the visualizer shows it since a backslash must be escaped.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, that string *really* has single backslashes in. Print it out to the console and you'll see that.

If you look at it in the *debugger*, you'll see the backslashes escaped - but the string itself has single backslashes. This bites lots of people :(

Comment: You where right however It is not saving output is C:\Temp\data_04 12 20:43 2012.txt

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, it's impossible to know what you mean by "not saving output".

Comment: what version of windows will finally deprecate then obsolete the back slash as meaning both escape AND path delimiter!?

Answer (score 9):

It is actually the forward slashes that are illegal in filename. Replace the forward slashes with something legal and try again.

Comment: @Servy, you are right, my built in parser bailed out on first error.

Answer (score 0):

```
String fileName = String.Format(@"C:\Temp\data_{0}.txt",DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss"));
```

Output: `C:\Temp\data_12042012214358.txt`

or use

```
String fileName = String.Format(@"C:\Temp\data_{0}.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH-mm-ss"));
```

Output: `C:\Temp\data_12.04.2012 21-45-03.txt`

Comment: This does not compile. You should have double backslashes or a @ before the first quote.

Comment: you can't use \T and \d without the @ althouth I do believe there is a way to add \ as a string I can't remember how

Comment: "C:\\Temp\\data_{0}.txt" allows it. By adding a \ you are saying the the next character is literal.

Comment: sorry i fixed it after posting it, forgot the @. Also i have added outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a format:

```
String fileName = @"C:\Temp\data_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM d HH mm yyyy") + ".txt";
```

Comment: @Servy Yes,  trying to be quick..  :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it shows two backslashes in the variable value because the ­\ is escaped. If you print the variable value, you should see that it only have one backslash.