# How to concatenate string with a backslash with another string

Tags: c#, join, backslash

How can I concatenate the string `"\u"` with `"a string"` to get "\u0000"?

My code creates two backslashes:

```
string a = @"\u" + "0000";  //ends up being "\\\u0000";
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: i  am using c# language

Comment: I want to search a sting in another string:                       if (code2.StartsWith(@"\u" + strUnicodeOfMiddleChar) == true)

Comment: You need the escape the character like this:  `string a = "\\u" + "0000";`.  [Character escapes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx).

Comment: What result do you expect in `a` anyway?

Comment: possible duplicate of [File name has two backslashes C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130400/file-name-has-two-backslashes-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, I think you want to build a single-char string from an arbitrary Unicode value (4 hex digits). So given the string "0000", you want to convert that into the string "\u0000", i.e., a string containing a single character.

I think this is what you want:

```
string  f = "0000";    // Or whatever
int     n = int.Parse(f, NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
string  s = ((char) n).ToString();
```

The resulting string `s` is `"\u0000"`, which you can then use for your search.

(With corrections suggested by Thomas Levesque.)

Answer (score 4):

The escape sequence `\uXXXX` is part of the language's syntax and represents a single Unicode character. By contrast, `@"\u"` and `"0000"` are two different strings, with a total of six characters. Concatenating them won't magically turn them into a single Unicode escape.
If you're trying to convert a Unicode code point into a single-character string, do this:

```
char.ConvertFromUtf32(strUnicodeOfMiddleChar).ToString()
```

BTW, don't use `== true`; it's redundant.

Comment: So your check becomes: if (code2.StartsWith(char.ConvertFromUtf32(0000))) { /* Your action */ }

Answer (score 2):

> the line below creates tow backslash:
>
> ```
> string a = @"\u" + "0000"; //a ends up being "\\u0000";
> ```

No, it doesn't; the debugger shows "\" as "\", because that's how you write a backslash in C# (when you don't prefix the string with @). If you print that string, you will see `\u0000`, not `\\u0000`.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, that string really has single backslash in. Print it out to the console and you'll see that.

Answer (score 2):

[Escape](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx) your characters correctly!!

Both:

```
// I am an escaped '\'.   
string a = "\\u" + "0000";
```

And:

```
// I am a literal string.
string a = @"\u" + "0000";
```

Will work just fine.  But, and I am going out on a limb here, I am guessing that you are trying to escape a Unicode Character and Hex value so, to do that, you need:

```
// I am an escaped Unicode Sequence with a Hex value.
char a = '\uxxxx';
```