# c# File.Exists always return false using value property

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

During debugging I found something annoying.
I have a file existing on my drive, I'm wondering why if I use the file exists function it always returns false, using property value. I try also in Immediate Window here are the results

```
ACGateLoginSystem.MAP_PATH == @"‪D:\Capture001.png" | true

?File.Exists(ACGateLoginSystem.MAP_PATH) | false

?File.Exists("D:\\Capture001.png") | true
```

I'm using windows 10 latest build, and visual studio 2017.

Comment: Might be something related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130400/file-name-has-two-backslashes-c-sharp)

Comment: The boolean values you've put on the side, are those supposed to be commends or shorthand operators?

Comment: @Adriani6 those boolean values are the result that he is getting during debugging, I feel. Don't you think so?

Comment: The | and the boolean value are the immediate window results.

Comment: @user3851362 You may check the answer I have posted and it that doesn't solve your issue then post your complete code.

Comment: also I using japanese version.
I'm wording if have any effects.

Comment: Please some some more real code; what is behind `ACGateLoginSystem.MAP_PATH`. The question shows it in a quite confusing way; the `==` in `ACGateLoginSystem.MAP_PATH == @"‪D:\Capture001.png` looks like a comparison instead of an assignment. I know it isn't as it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Following is working for me.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class LoginSystem
    {
        public string MAP_PATH { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoginSystem ACGateLoginSystem = new LoginSystem();
            ACGateLoginSystem.MAP_PATH = @"D:\1.png";

            if (File.Exists(ACGateLoginSystem.MAP_PATH))
                Console.WriteLine("File Exists");

            if (File.Exists("D:\\1.png"))
                Console.WriteLine("File Exists - with direct path");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Output: [image]

Comment: Its detected in your solution, however in the project still encounter the problem.

ACGateLoginSystem.MAP_PATH = @"‪D:\1.png";

then I use the immediate window this is the result

?File.Exists(ACGateLoginSystem.MAP_PATH)

false
?File.Exists(@"D:\1.png")
true

Comment: May be problem is somewhere else. You need to post the whole code

Answer (score 0):

The backslash character \ is a special character in C# (and any C-like language). It is used in conjunction with a second one to define special character. Thus, this would work:

```
File.Exists("D:\\Capture001.png")
```

and this should work

```
File.Exists(@"D:\Capture001.png")
```

and this won't work

```
File.Exists("D:\Capture001.png")
```